# Angular 2: importing router bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm stuck as to why I can't get router to import as a dependency. In console I get the error:

```
system.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Looking at the google examples they're using practically the same setup so I'm not too sure where I've gone wrong. If I comment out the import for router it all works as expected.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <main>Loading...</main>

    <script src="lib/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.config({defaultJSExtensions: true});
    </script>

    <script src="lib/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/router.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('index').catch(console.log.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
```

index.js:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {routerInjectables} from 'angular2/router';
import {stepOne} from 'step-one/step-one';

@Component({
    selector: 'main'
})

/*@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'StepOne', component: stepOne, useAsDefault: true}
])*/

@View({
    template: `
    <h1>INIT</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})

class Main {
    constructor(){}
}

bootstrap(Main, [routerInjectables]);
```

Comment: where you have import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seeems there are many errors in your code few are here...

correct your imports with the given below as of angular2 is in beta now...

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
```

you have not provide router-directives import this one too from here and add into the directive list.

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
```

better way you can use this in the index.ts

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'main',
        template: `
        <h1>INIT</h1>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>`, 
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    })
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', component: stepOne, name: 'StepOne', useAsDefault: true}
])

class Main {
    constructor(){}
}

bootstrap(Main, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

and your index.html should be like this.

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions: true,
                 map: {
                    rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs'
                },
                packages: {
                    rxjs: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
                }
            });

</script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('Main');

</script>
```

Comment: I was moving build files via gulp but I've just used the node modules folder for now... I changed the bootstrap parameter to ROUTER_PROVIDERS and all now works. Thanks!